# Cypress:Can we set tolerance level for matchImageSnapshot

Tags: snapshot, cypress

I am using cy.matchImageSnapshot for my image comparison testing.
Sometimes it fails for slight differences. Is there any way to mention a tolerance level so that for Eg. up to 80% match i can still pass test like that?
My code looks like below

```
cy.get('.itl-exit-info-panel > .ngcope').root().matchImageSnapshot('MyDashboard2');
```

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should specify this is from a plugin, and link it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible to set the tolerance level through few config parameters. Here is a sample,

```js
matchImageSnapshot('MyDashboard2', {
  failureThreshold: 0.03, // threshold for entire image
  failureThresholdType: 'percent', // percent of image or number of pixels
  customDiffConfig: { threshold: 0.1 }, // threshold for each pixel
  capture: 'viewport', // capture viewport in screenshot
});
```

I would suggest you to read through the documentation here - https://github.com/palmerhq/cypress-image-snapshot#options